# Unit testing a controller throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net, autofixture

I have a controller with the following signature:

```
public CustomerTypeController(
    IHttpContextAccessor accessor,
    IPrincipalProvider provider,
    IMapper mapper, 
    ILogger<CustomerTypeController> logger,
    ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService)
{ }
```

For now my `Theory` looks like this:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void GetWhenHasCustomerTypesShouldReturnOneCustomerType(
    IFixture fixture,
    [Frozen] Mock<ICustomerTypeService> service,
    CustomerTypeController sut)
{
    //Arrange
    var items = fixture.CreateMany<Model.CustomerType>(3).ToList();

    //Act
    var result = sut.Get(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<OkResult>(result);
}
```

When I run this test as-is, I get the following exception:

> AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath : AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BindingInfo because creation unexpectedly failed with exception. Please refer to the inner exception to investigate the root cause of the failure.

> Inner exception messages:
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.Object' must implement 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IModelBinder' to be used as a model binder. (Parameter 'value')

What am I doing wrong, and how do I solve the problem?

Comment: You asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602133/how-to-unit-test-a-controller-with-xunit-moq-and-autofixture) already

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski 2 questions for 2 different problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You should decorate the controller parameter in your test method with the `[NoAutoProperties]` attribute.

```cs
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void GetWhenHasCustomerTypesShouldReturnOneCustomerType(
    IFixture fixture,
    [Frozen] Mock<ICustomerTypeService> service,
    [NoAutoProperties] CustomerTypeController sut)
{
    //Arrange
    var items = fixture.CreateMany<Model.CustomerType>(3).ToList();

    //Act
    var result = sut.Get(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<OkResult>(result);
}
```

### Update

Now that I know the AutoFixture code-base a little better, I wanted to understand why does this actually fix the issue.

The `Greedy` attribute normally instructs AutoFixture to use the constructor with the largest number of parameters, which should have nothing to do with the fix.

As the error message states, the exception occurs when a property is being set and the property is expecting a value that implements `IModelBinder`. The origin of the error is the `BinderType` property of the `BindingInfo` class, which is of type `System.Type`. By default AutoFixture will resolve `Type` as `System.Object`, which explains the error message.

When the `Greedy` attribute is applied, this customizes AutoFixture to create an instance of the property type, using a custom factory. The resulting builder graph node, (likely by accident) skips setting any properties, on the created instance.

Taking this into consideration, a more fitting resolution should be a using the `NoAutoProperties` attribute. This will explicitly instruct AutoFixture to ignore all auto-properties in the decorated type, but will leave the constructor query as "modest".

Since adding the attribute everywhere might get annoying and tedious, I suggest customizing AutoFixture to ignore all properties from `ControllerBase`, in the domain customization. Also in case you're using property injection, this will allow AutoFixture to instantiate the controller properties.

```cs
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(() => new Fixture().Customize(
            new CompositeCustomization(
                new AutoMoqCustomization(),
                new AspNetCustomization())))
    {
    }
}

public class AspNetCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new ControllerBasePropertyOmitter());
    }
}

public class ControllerBasePropertyOmitter : Omitter
{
    public ControllerBasePropertyOmitter()
        : base(new OrRequestSpecification(GetPropertySpecifications()))
    {
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IRequestSpecification> GetPropertySpecifications()
    {
        return typeof(ControllerBase).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanWrite)
            .Select(x => new PropertySpecification(x.PropertyType, x.Name));
    }
}
```

If you need the properties in `ControllerBase` for some reason then just instruct AutoFixture how to properly create `BindingInfo` instances.

---

#### Original answer

You should decorate the controller parameter in your test method with the `[Greedy]` attribute.

```cs
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void GetWhenHasCustomerTypesShouldReturnOneCustomerType(
    IFixture fixture,
    [Frozen] Mock<ICustomerTypeService> service,
    [Greedy] CustomerTypeController sut)
{
    //Arrange
    var items = fixture.CreateMany<Model.CustomerType>(3).ToList();

    //Act
    var result = sut.Get(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<OkResult>(result);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify here, because I got the wrong end of the stick at first, you decorate the controller parameter in the test method, not the controller itself. Works a treat, thanks!

Comment: @Clarkeye thank you for mentioning it. Your comment motivated me review and improve my answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Ah, that looks great, thanks Andrei

Answer (score 0):

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use an attribute, you can customise a fixture like so:

```
Fixture.Customize<BindingInfo>(cc => cc.OmitAutoProperties());
```

In my case I am using a generic base test class with a `Fixture` and various extensions of AutoFixture functionality that I want to reuse. The base class creates my `sut` and I only want to modify its behaviour in some test classes.